# Thread runs 2 times on heroku platform

Tags: python, multithreading, heroku, server

I'm building a binance trading bot. When I upload it to your Heroku server, the 'printt' function seems to be run 2-3 times. When I run it myself in the terminal, it starts once and works properly.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
global letter
letter = "a"
def printt():
    while True:
        print(letter)

@app.route("/")
def helloWorld():
     return "Hello world"
@app.route("/webhook", methods=["POST"])
def webhook():
     data = json.loads(request.data)
     letter = data['letter'] 
import threading
t1 = threading.Thread(target= printt)
t1.start()
```

For example, when I post, I send 'b', but the program prints both 'a' and 'b'.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is in your `Procfile`? Gunicorn, for example, [runs a few processes by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#basic-configuration).

Comment: Only gunicorn app:app

Comment: all variables created outside functions are global - and you don't need `global letter` outside functions. You should use `global letter` inside `webhook` to inform this  function that it has to assign new value `data['letter']` to global variable `letter` instead of creating local variable `letter`

Comment: I think I solved the problem. the program is started twice on the server. I put print("1") statement at the beginning of the program. printed 1 twice and the program started. how do i prevent this

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution, link:
[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68549612/thread-in-python-gets-started-twice-on-heroku)